# Oracle APEX 19.2 Calendar Create Link - Send selected date to linked page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a calendar region on a page and have the Calendar region attributes set to Create Link to another page on date selection. This is great but I would like the target page item to be set to the date I have selected on the calendar. Is this possible? I can't seem to find an option to pass the calendar date selection to the target page.

Many thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

To pass the selected calendar date just set the value to:

```
&APEX$NEW_START_DATE.
```

[image: Oracle APEX calendar get current date]

You can find complete information in the Oracle Application Express App Builder User's Guide:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/creating-calendars.htm#HTMDB05006

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27933870)

Comment: @k.s.: This isn’t _just_ a link—and that’s especially apparent once you edit the answer to move the image inline, which the author didn’t have a high enough reputation to do themselves.